# Apply Delt only on consecutive days

Tags: r, date, quantmod

I have the following data and I would like to apply `quantmod::Delt`, only on consecutive days: `Delt(data$ch, k = 1, type = 'arithmetic')` returns the k-period percent difference within one series:

> (x2(t) - x1(t-k))/x1(t-k)

I would like `Delt` to return `NA` when the dates are not consecutive. Here's a reproducible example:

```
data <- structure(list(Date = structure(c(15706, 15707, 15708, 15709, 
15715, 15716, 15762, 15763, 15764, 12116), class = "Date"), ch = c(12L, 
23L, 4L, 78L, 120L, 94L, 36L, 2L, 41L, 22L)), .Names = c("Date", 
"ch"), row.names = c(NA, -10L), class = "data.frame")
indx <- cumsum(c(TRUE,abs(diff(data$Date))>1))
require(quantmod)
ave(data$ch, indx, FUN=function(x) c(Delt(x),NA))
# [1]    NA  0.92 -0.83 18.50    NA -0.22    NA -0.94 19.50    NA
# Warning messages:
# 1: In `split<-.default`(`*tmp*`, g, value = lapply(split(x, g), FUN)) :
#   number of items to replace is not a multiple of replacement length
# 2: In `split<-.default`(`*tmp*`, g, value = lapply(split(x, g), FUN)) :
#   number of items to replace is not a multiple of replacement length
# 3: In `split<-.default`(`*tmp*`, g, value = lapply(split(x, g), FUN)) :
#   number of items to replace is not a multiple of replacement length
# 4: In `split<-.default`(`*tmp*`, g, value = lapply(split(x, g), FUN)) :
#   number of items to replace is not a multiple of replacement length
```

The output I am trying to obtain is:

```
[1]  0.92 -0.83 18.50    NA -0.22    NA -0.94 19.50    NA
```

I also do not fully understand the warning messages. Suggestions/workaround anyone?

Comment: I think you don't need to concatenate with `NA`. i.e. `ave(data$ch, indx, FUN=function(x) Delt(x))[-1]` should work

Comment: @akrun it doesn't work. What works is the following:
replace(Delt(df1$ch, k=1, type='arithmetic'), abs(diff(df1$Date)) > 1, NA)

Comment: For your dataset, I get `ave(data$ch, indx, FUN=function(x) Delt(x))[-1]#
[1]  0.9166667 -0.8260870 18.5000000         NA -0.2166667         NA -0.9444444
[8] 19.5000000         NA`

Comment: @akrun that is right, I must have done something wrong. Now this command doesn't work: replace(Delt(df1$ch, k=1, type='arithmetic'), abs(diff(df1$Date)) > 1, NA)